# Is there a way to make a Python script consider the default proxy settings of the machine?

Tags: python, proxy

I'm on an organization's network and I set proxy using 'set proxy=' in cmd before running a script. If I convert the Python file into an exe, it doesn't work because proxy commands are not passed. How to overcome this? How to make Python consider the default proxy settings without passing them every time?

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw that ? [Python Proxy Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980877/python-proxy-settings)
It seems to fit your need.

```
import os
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "http://user_id:pass@proxy:port"
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your quick reply. I was wondering about the elimination of proxy entirely so as to make Python consider the system proxy settings without the need for passing them in the code